# Persistently being signed out of iCloud across all devices

Tags: macos, icloud, password

For a week now, I'll get a notification at least once a day, if not more, telling me that I am to sign back into iCloud. I then have to go across all my devices and enter the password. Every so often the notification refuses to let me sign in without changing my password. I'm on my fourth password now and honestly running out of ones I can use (I won't be able to remember them at this rate). It's becoming very frustrating because I don't know what's causing this.

I've signed out on all my devices purposefully to try and see if there was some bug with a server token causing the trouble, but nothing really came of it. I'm not sure what I can do at this point?

I've tried to find other solutions to this problem but most people figured it out with the reset or by finding they were entering a password incorrectly.

Can anyone advise on how I might stop these constant requests? Thanks.

Comment: Might be someone else trying to access your account. Did you check the trusted phone numbers on your Apple ID? Secondary emails? Are your security questions easy enough for a third party to guess? Is Two-factor authentication on?

Comment: Two factor authentication is enabled. I can't tell if anyone is trying to access my account. There are no sign in emails or reset emails besides those I trigger when forced to go through the password reset. I've never accepted anything through email (reset password link) either, so I don't think I've been phished. If anyone does have access, they must have a way to persistently obtain the new password without my knowledge. It feels like something is messing with my logins but I'm not sure how to verify what.

Comment: If they managed to add their phone or email to your Apple ID, they may get access after you change your password, although they would have to change it (unless they had your new passwords also, which would be weird).

Comment: Well I have checked my security settings online, and the only mobile phone there is mine, and no other emails have been added as a backup. This would suggest its a software bug, since there seems to be no attempt to hijack the account itself. At least not so far.